# Perl's taint mode in PHP

Tags: php, perl, mode, taint

Just wondering... is there a PHP equivalent to Perl's Taint Mode? I don't think there is, but thought I'd ask.

Comment: In all "is there an equivalent in X to Y" questions, it really expands the number of people who could answer if you provide a brief description of what Y is/does or at least give a link to documentation.

Comment: @spudly - apologies, turns out the link I posted was a dud - sorry for wasting your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested by: http://wiki.php.net/rfc/taint

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a patch was made...

http://blog.php-security.org/archives/92-CORE-GRASP-PHP-Tainted-Mode.html